# What does a CSS class like ul.lsidebar a{} mean?

Tags: css, html, class, xhtml

what is this called? i have never experienced it with css.

I am guessing that that class will only affect that tag. if you know please give me some examples of how to use this. i am talking about the (`ul`) part.

code is below:

```
ul.lsidebar a{}
```

Comment: What is which part called?

Comment: @minitech: “i am talking about the (ul.) part.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is targetting the class name `lsidebar` specifically for the DOM node `ul`

Example:

```
<div class="lsidebar">
    <a href="#">ab</a>
</div>
<ul class="lsidebar">
  <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you do `.lsidebar a{}` it would target `a` in the descendant nodes of both the `div` and `ul`

But in this case, `ul.lsidebar a{}` targets specifically `a` in descendant nodes of `ul` (the `a` with text `a` and `b` in this case).

[This link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm) might help you understand how CSS is targeted in the DOM

Comment: i am still confused on it though. i am very new to programming in css and html. can you go into more detail please?

Comment: @JoeyScotto Just added an example. This should help you understand better. Also the link should

Comment: so i think i'm starting to get it. please correct me if i'm wrong. it is where you make one class and can apply it to only the elements you target so you dont have to make multiple classes.

Comment: Well. kind of right - If you have multiple Nodes (targets) with the same class name, you can use this syntax to filter only the specific targets you want to apply the css to.

Comment: so it applies it to only certain tags and adds on elements?

Comment: not "certain" tags, but "specific" tags - `ul` in this case. The reason i say that - If there are multiple tags with the same class name, the properties would apply to __only__ `a` within `ul`s, filtering out all the others

Comment: alright so i think i got it now, if you have a list for example any element inside of those tags that was specified would be styled if it is under something like ul.lsidebar li{}

Comment: OH YEAH THAT'S HOW I ROLL. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`ul.lsidebar` means the following in HTML:

```
 <ul class="lsidebar"></ul>
```

This is commonly called a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

See that little `a` at the end? That is called a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) which means it will style the following HTML element:

```
 <ul class="lsidebar">
      <a href="#">I'll be styled!</a>
 </ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: not to be weird but are you a real person or a computer. i am new here

Comment: but i am stil;l really confused on how this would be used. can you give me a very clear example?

Comment: There are a lot of people on stackoverflow at any given time! Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

There may be several elements that belong to the class "lsidebar". with `ul.lsidebar` the code references only the elements "lsidebar" which are unordered lists (ul).

The "a" references the anchor elements inside the unordered lists (links).

The karthikr example is pertinent. In his example, the code will style the a and b links.